# How to create Google map server side clustering with MySql and Zoom level ?

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

How to create Google map server side clustering with `MySql` query taking the bound co ordinates and `Zoom level` in `PHP`?

There are few sites done the same things:

- http://jory.dk/AreaGMC/MapClustering.html
- http://www.kaufda.de/Berlin/Geschaefte-Laeden-Shops - (please zoom
  out)

Answer (score -1):

you can use my clustering app. It uses postgis and not mysql. Mysql and its geographic extensions is not a good choice for this type of operation as it lacks many features which postgis offers. 
jory.dk is also good using a grid based centroid. The anycluster also uses centroids, but on top of a kmeans algorithm which makes the markers less aligned as you can use larger grid cells. Zoom in a few levels on jory.dk and see how you can anticipate the grid as the markers are aligned.
anycluster is free and open source:

https://github.com/biodiv/anycluster